# Como hacer editable un campo en un aspx gridview?

Tags: c#, datagrid, aspx

Estoy modificando una aplicación ASPX, necesito agregar un combo box con determinado diccionario de datos. básicamente duplique la manera en la que se definieron las otras columnas y cree un data source como los que ya estaban creados, a mi ver, todo esta igual... Al correr la aplicación aparece el nuevo campo, el combo box tiene los elementos correctos, pero no me permite seleccionar un elemento, casi como si tuviera la propiedad read only. no encuentro cual es la diferencia, ¿Que debo hacer para que sea editable? comparto imagen y código.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="eventos_dtl_com" OnDataBound="ASPxGridView3_DataBound" OnBeforeGetCallbackResult="ASPxGridView3_BeforeGetCallbackResult" SettingsPager-PageSizeItemSettings-ShowAllItem="true" SettingsPager-PageSizeItemSettings-ShowPopupShadow="true" KeyFieldName="serie_int;folio_int;pt;clavePed" OnBatchUpdate="ASPxGridView3_BatchUpdate"  OnRowUpdated="ASPxGridView3_RowUpdated" Theme="Office2010Black" OnHtmlDataCellPrepared="ASPxGridView3_HtmlDataCellPrepared" OnInitNewRow="ASPxGridView3_InitNewRow" OnCellEditorInitialize="ASPxGridView3_CellEditorInitialize">
 <SettingsPager AlwaysShowPager="True" NumericButtonCount="5">
    <PageSizeItemSettings ShowAllItem="True"></PageSizeItemSettings>
 </SettingsPager>
 <SettingsEditing Mode="Inline" EditFormColumnCount="10" UseFormLayout="False">
    <BatchEditSettings EditMode="Row" />
 </SettingsEditing>
 <Settings ShowGroupedColumns="True" ShowGroupFooter="VisibleAlways" ShowFooter="True" ShowStatusBar="Visible" ShowTitlePanel="True" />
 <SettingsBehavior AutoExpandAllGroups="True" AllowFixedGroups="True" AllowFocusedRow="True" ConfirmDelete="True" />
 <SettingsPopup>
    <EditForm AllowResize="True" />
 </SettingsPopup>
 <SettingsText Title="Facturas a a generar" />
 <Columns>
    <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="0" ShowEditButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowNewButtonInHeader="True"></dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="partida" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="1" ReadOnly="True"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="serie_int" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="2" ReadOnly="True"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="folio_int" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="3" ReadOnly="True"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="pt" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="4" Width="150px"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ptDesc" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="5" Width="200px"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="clavePed" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="7">
        <PropertiesComboBox>
            <Items>
                 <dx:ListEditItem Text="Return" Value="RT" />
                 <dx:ListEditItem Text="Definitive" Value="A1" />
            </Items>
        </PropertiesComboBox>
    </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="FraccionArancelaria" VisibleIndex="8">
        <PropertiesComboBox EnableSynchronization="False" DataSourceID="ComercioFraccion" ValueField="fraccion" TextField="descr"></PropertiesComboBox>
    </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CantidadAduana" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="9" UnboundType="Decimal">                                                              
        <PropertiesTextEdit DisplayFormatString="{0:0.000}" DisplayFormatInEditMode="True"></PropertiesTextEdit>
    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="UnidadAduana" VisibleIndex="10">
        <PropertiesComboBox EnableSynchronization="False" DataSourceID="ComercioUnidad" ValueField="UnidadAduana" TextField="Unidad"></PropertiesComboBox>
    </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ValorUnitarioAduana" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="11">
        <PropertiesTextEdit DisplayFormatInEditMode="True" DisplayFormatString="{0:0.00}"></PropertiesTextEdit>
    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ValorDolares" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="12" ReadOnly="True">
        <PropertiesTextEdit DisplayFormatInEditMode="True" DisplayFormatString="{0:0.00}"></PropertiesTextEdit>
    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="ClaveUnidad" VisibleIndex="6">
        <PropertiesComboBox EnableSynchronization="False" DataSourceID="CfdiClaveUnidad" ValueField="clave" TextField="descr"></PropertiesComboBox>
    </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
 </Columns>
```

Muestro el combo box desplegado, y aun asi no permite seleccionar elementos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: dices que el combo tiene los elementos correctos, pero no permite la seleccion, como es eso? sino permite seleccionas como desplega para que veas que los elementos son los correctos

Comment: Agregue una imagen, se despliega el contenido del combo pero sin permitir seleccionar ningún elemento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si revisamos los foros de este componente `ASPxGridView`

[GridViewDataComboBoxColumn - Can't select any entries in a ASPxComboBox in inline edit mode](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q275748/gridviewdatacomboboxcolumn-can-t-select-any-entries-in-a-aspxcombobox-in-inline-edit-mode)

menciona que el valor que ingreses en `FieldName` debe ser una propiedad que exista en el origen de datos, entonces la columna  `ClaveUnidad` debe existir en `DataSourceID="eventos_dtl_com"`

Comment: No me permite incluir también el código completo del datasource pero ya están incluidos también <asp:Parameter Name="ClaveUnidad" Type="String" />, estan en <InsertParameters> y en  <UpdateParameters>

Comment: per esta ese campo en el SelectCommand ? porque mencione que tiene que estar en el origen de datos que carga el grid

Comment: en el SelectCommand solo esta serie, folio y clavecli, aun asi no se ven afectados los otros campos

Comment: intenta agregando en ese select un campo con un valor fijo como ser SELECT X AS ClaveUnidad para ver si al retornar un valor en el origen de datos permite la seleccion, en donde X si se puede que sea un valor valido del combo

Comment: Agregando en cada consulta los campos emparejo el formulario